# Need to retrieve all users using json object python from html page

Tags: python, rest, api

I am learning Rest API using python. And using the html page https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/examples/profile.html#

How can I retrieve all the users from here using json object?

Tried the following code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = '''
<span class="username">
<a href="#">Jonathan Burke Jr.</a>
<a href="#" class="pull-right btn-box-tool"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
spans = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "username"})
for span in spans:
    links = span.find_all('a')
    for link in links:
        print(link['href'])
```

Also did an inspect on one of the user name in the link mentioned
and it shows

```
<span class="username">
                          <a href="#">Jonathan Burke Jr.</a>
                          <a href="#" class="pull-right btn-box-tool"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                        </span>attrs["username"])
```

Comment: what is your code so far?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hey mind you that what you're trying to do has nothing to do with REST, or API's in general.

That said you can use a neat python module called BeautifulSoup that can be used to parse HTML pages.

**EDIT**

Try this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/examples/profile.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
name_box = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'username'})
print(name_box)
```

Does this help anyhow?

**EDIT 2 **

If you wanna find all entries instead, use

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/examples/profile.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
name_box = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'username'})
for name in name_box:
  print(name.find('a', href=True))
```

Comment: One of the profile user name is saved as 
<span class="username">
                          <a href="#">Jonathan Burke Jr.</a>
                          <a href="#" class="pull-right btn-box-tool"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                        </span>

I tried this as you suggested but i get an error, being new to this I am a bit slow. 
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
element = soup.find("div", class_="username")
print(element.attrs["username"])
jsonData = json.loads(element.attrs["username"]) 
print (jsonData['name'])

Comment: Hi, post your code as a edit on your original post, and also add the error you're getting. It's a bit hard to understand from the unformatted comment text.

Comment: Its my first question here, i will learn this too. The post is edited with proper formatting. Thanks!

Comment: Its perfect Sir! So another question since this html page has 4 blocks of user information, in other words shows 4 more users do I need to repeat the same for each of the user ?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. Check out the new edit.